# Assume Role and write temporary AWS credentials to ~/.aws/credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

- I am using MFA token on my main account **main**
- I am assuming a role **roleX**
- My `~/.aws/credentials` has the access key id and secret access key for **main**
- My `~/.aws/config` has the `role_arn` and `mfa_serial` of role **roleX**. It also has `source_profile = main` too.
- I think this might *not* be a suitable task for a Shell script
- I not a proficient Python programmer, but I would like the practice

The outcomes I am aiming for are:

1)  my script will print the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_session_token` to the `~/.aws/credentials` file, automatically updating the **roleX** profile found there.

Examples:

`~/.aws/config`

```
[profile roleX]
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:mfa/felipe
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::987654321098:role/roleX
source_profile = main
```

`~/.aws/credentials`

```
[main]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret
```

**After**

`~/.aws/credentials`

```
[main]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret

[roleX]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret
aws_session_token = temp
```

Comment: if the structure of ~/.aws/config is remaining constant then its just a small work of readline and split

Comment: This seems like a bad design choice.  The aws-cli has support for reading these values from [environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html), which seems more appropriate than modifying your config file with transient data like this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way I could think of:

```
aws_access_key_id = ""
aws_secret_access_key = ""
aws_access_key_id = ""
aws_secret_access_key = ""
aws_session_token = ""

with open('~/.aws/config','r') as file1:
    lines = file1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
         # if line.startswith('aws_access_key_id')
         # then remove the string and keep the end
         # ...

with open('~/.aws/credentials','r') as file1:
    lines = file1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
         # if line.startswith('aws_access_key_id')
         # then remove the string and keep the end
         # ...

with open('~/.aws/credentials', 'a') as file_out:
    file_out.write("[main]")
    file_out.write("aws_access_key_id = {}".format(aws_access_key_id))
    file_out.write("aws_secret_access_key = {}".format(aws_secret_access_key))
    file_out.write("")
    file_out.write("[roleX]")
    file_out.write("aws_access_key_id = {}".format(aws_access_key_id))
    file_out.write("aws_secret_access_key = {}".format(aws_secret_access_key))
    file_out.write("aws_session_token = {}".format(aws_session_token))
```

Comment: are you sure that line `file_out.write("aws_secret_access_key = {}.format(aws_secret_access_key)")`
`would work?